# changing the value of a form field with a custom method?

Tags: javascript, forms

I created a method called `removeValue` to remove the value of formfields. Every time the user clicks on it, I put in the onclick event with the function to be executed, in the html, it gives this error: "cannot reference to variable of ..." (something like that). Why is that?

I thought the keyword `this` always refers to the object being called, if I write `this.value ="";` directly in the HTML, it works. Why is that?

```
function removeValue () {  
    if (this.value != "") {
        this.value = ""; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the window object in this case. Pass your element to the function like this:

```
function removeValue(element) {
    element.value = '';
}
```

---

```
<input onclick="removeValue(this)" type="text">
```

I think it would be better if you bind the function to the `onfocus` event, because then it gets also called when switching to the input field with tab.

Comment: thanks for the answer, why does it refer to the window object, I thought this always refers to the object where the method is being called upon?